# While WebApi access I'm getting Login Html Page as response instead api result?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I have WebApp and WebAPI register into same Azure AD.

I'm trying to call WebAPI from WebApp.

I have added service WebAPI into my WebApp in azure AD Applcaition. like below - [image]

When I run WebAPI it will give me login screen after login success I can access WebAPI methods. This is normal behavior.

When I run WebApp it will act same login screen and after login success i can see WebApp.

Now I want to call WebAPI methods from WebApp but I do not want login screen for WebAPI because When I will run WebApp i will get login screen and after login I hope by using same user I should able to access WebAPI without again doing login stuff , as i have token which will work for both WebApp and WebAPI.

WebAPI code -

Startup.Auth.cs

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
        private static string aadInstance = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
        private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

        public static readonly string Authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

        // This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
        string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

       public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = ClientId,
            Authority = Authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = PostLogoutRedirectUri
        });


    }
        }

        private static string EnsureTrailingSlash(string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                value = string.Empty;
            }

            if (!value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                return value + "/";
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
```

TestController.cs

```
[Authorize]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/getdata")]
        public IEnumerable<string> GetData()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
```

WebApp code -

Startup.Auth.cs

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
        private static string aadInstance = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
        private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

        public static readonly string Authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

        // This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
        string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = Authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                       AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) => 
                       {
                           var code = context.Code;
                           ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                           string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                           AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                           AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                               code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId).Result;

                           return Task.FromResult(0);
                       }
                    }
                });
        }

        private static string EnsureTrailingSlash(string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                value = string.Empty;
            }

            if (!value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                return value + "/";
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
```

HomeController.cs

```
[Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static string clientIdWebApp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:clientIdWebApp"];
        private static string clientIdWebApi = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:clientIdWebApi"];
        private static string clientSecretWebApp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:clientSecretWebApp"];
        private static string aadInstance = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
        private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        private static string PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
        Uri redirectUri = new Uri(PostLogoutRedirectUri);
        public static readonly string Authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

        public ActionResult Index()
        {          
                return View();
        }

        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
            try
            {
                AuthenticationResult result = null;

                string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier").Value;
                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority, new ADALTokenCache(userObjectID));
                ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientIdWebApp, clientSecretWebApp);
                //AcquireTokenSilentAsync should have to work as i'm accessing WebAPI using same user I logged in to WebApp 
                result = authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(clientIdWebApi,credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId)).Result;
                // gettign exception {"Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken"} but I got match id into cache.
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://MYWEBAPI/api/getdata");
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                // Return the user's profile in the view.
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (AdalException ex)
            {
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

AdalTokenCache.cs - same for both WebApp and WebAPI

```
 public class ADALTokenCache : TokenCache
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        private string userId;
        private UserTokenCache Cache;

        public ADALTokenCache(string signedInUserId)
        {
            // associate the cache to the current user of the web app
            userId = signedInUserId;
            this.AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeWrite = BeforeWriteNotification;
            // look up the entry in the database
            Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
            // place the entry in memory
            this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits,"ADALCache"));
        }

        // clean up the database
        public override void Clear()
        {
            base.Clear();
            var cacheEntry = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
            db.UserTokenCacheList.Remove(cacheEntry);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Notification raised before ADAL accesses the cache.
        // This is your chance to update the in-memory copy from the DB, if the in-memory version is stale
        void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            if (Cache == null)
            {
                // first time access
                Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
            }
            else
            { 
                // retrieve last write from the DB
                var status = from e in db.UserTokenCacheList
                             where (e.webUserUniqueId == userId)
                select new
                {
                    LastWrite = e.LastWrite
                };

                // if the in-memory copy is older than the persistent copy
                if (status.First().LastWrite > Cache.LastWrite)
                {
                    // read from from storage, update in-memory copy
                    Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
                }
            }
            this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits, "ADALCache"));
        }

        // Notification raised after ADAL accessed the cache.
        // If the HasStateChanged flag is set, ADAL changed the content of the cache
        void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            // if state changed
            if (this.HasStateChanged)
            {
                if (Cache == null)
                {
                    Cache = new UserTokenCache
                    {
                        webUserUniqueId = userId
                    };
                }

                Cache.cacheBits = MachineKey.Protect(this.Serialize(), "ADALCache");
                Cache.LastWrite = DateTime.Now;

                // update the DB and the lastwrite 
                db.Entry(Cache).State = Cache.UserTokenCacheId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                this.HasStateChanged = false;
            }
        }

        void BeforeWriteNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            // if you want to ensure that no concurrent write take place, use this notification to place a lock on the entry
        }

        public override void DeleteItem(TokenCacheItem item)
        {
            base.DeleteItem(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That'll depend how your API authentication is configured.

Comment: let me updated my full code here in question